# How to abort function by timeout at JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to execute some function but if timeout expired I need to abort this function. I tried to use setTimeout and setImmediate. I wrote this example and used setInterval in callback for checking of working but it did't help me:

```
function waiter(timeout, fun) {
  var functionHandler = setImmediate(fun);
  var timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('stoped');
    clearImmediate(functionHandler);
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
  }, timeout);
  fun();
}

waiter(5000, () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('work');
  }, 500);
});
```

After clearImmediate and clearTimeout my interval still working. How I understood that method doesn't guarantee that my function will be aborted.
Does anybody have an idea how to abort function execution?

**UPDATE:**
Yes, I know that I should call clearInterval but it's just an example for work checking. For example I should parse some big data and if it doesn't can do it by timeout I need to cancel this function execution and call something else.

Comment: In order to stop an interval timer, you need to call `clearInterval`.

Comment: If I've understood the question in the comment correctly, the answer is no. Any call of a timer won't block the execution, and a `while` loop would continue until its end condition will be met, after that a timed function will be executed (if an infinite loop, any timed function is never executed).

Comment: After saw the update: If you've a long polling function, it is executed to the end, before any timed function can be run. So, not possible. Maybe consider to use a web worker for a long polling task?

Comment: @Teemu It doesn't sound good for me... But thanks

Comment: If you'd show a real (minimum) use-case, we'd might be able to understand your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clearXXX` functions don't abort functions that are currently running, they just remove functions from the async queue, so that they never start to run. JavaScript always executes code to its completion. You cannot interrupt code that's running in the main thread.

Comment: Okay, I understood. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your interval
and clear it by its name. So your interval is no longer anonymous, but you've got a reference for it.

```
let counter = 10;
let newYearCountdown = setInterval( () => {
    console.log(counter);
    counter--
    if (counter === 0) {
        console.log("HAPPY NEW YEAR!!");
// here i clear interval by its name.
        clearInterval(newYearCountdown);
    }
}, 1000);
```